# Is it safe to use my primary phone for debugging applications?

Tags: android, debugging, mobile

I don't have any other devices to use for testing.  I'm looking to test apps that I develop on my own Android phone but wonder if I could mess up my phone if I accidentally write some bad code.

Also, if I use emulators, are they good representations of real phones?

Comment: this mostly comes down to personal preference, however many people (myself included) I know use their personal phones for development. If you're just writing apps there shouldn't be anything you can do to damage your phone by writing "bad code". Emulators are good, but they aren't perfect, and you will find some devices have certain nuances that aren't shown in emulators (eg Samsung phones wouldn't show italic text in TextView widgets)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

This worked for me - as long as multi-touch isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that an emulator works fine for most things and are a good representation of the specific phone, **however** they are often much slower than physical devices.  **IF** you have your own android phone then I'd **highly recommend** using it for the convenience and the bonus of actually having tested your app on a real device.